# How to upload client-side generated image to Twitter as photo?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm currently generating an image using JavaScript+Canvas which I now need to be able to share with twitter as a photo.

What is the easiest way to do that?

Twitter cards won't work since there's no URL with the image to share. Or is the only option to upload the image to a service like imgur and then share it with twitter? Or is there a workaround to upload a base64 image to Twitter?

Comment: Does twitter only accept URLs or can you also send form-data? (like a typical `POST`)

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same scenario

Comment: @Tebo not yet, but I'll probably use a service like parse.com - there's no way to do it entirely on the client side.